# trying to make it check the excel if it does not match the next_monday date change it to tuesday

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I trying to have python read my excel file and if statements to check today is monday if so change it to next monday then do another if statement to check the excel file to check if there is any for next monday if true leave as is if not check next Tuesday. I was able to have it change it to Tuesday but unable to make sure to check for each col.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, MO, TU

now = now = DT.datetime.now()
nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=MO(+1))
next_monday = now - relativedelta(weekday=MO(+1))
next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")

hr_file = "Upcoming Hires.xlsx"
hr_file_readable = pd.read_excel(hr_file, sheet_name="New Hires")
hr_file_readable["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(hr_file_readable["Start Date"], errors = "coerce" ).dt.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
hr_file_readable = hr_file_readable["Start Date"] 

#this checks if today is monday or not
if next_monday == now:
    nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=MO(+2))
    hr_file_readable = hr_file_readable.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
    next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
    print(next_monday)

    if next_monday == hr_file_readable.all():
        nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=TU(+2))
        next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
        print(next_monday)

if next_monday == now:
    nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=MO(+2))
    hr_file_readable = hr_file_readable.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
    next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
    print(next_monday)
    
    if next_monday == hr_file_readable.all():
        nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=TU(+2))
        next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
        print(next_monday)
```

Comment: I hope you know, you actually checking/amending just a dataframe in pandas, not the actual excel file

Comment: how can i actual check the excel file then?

Comment: would i use ```pd.DataFrame()```?

Comment: you can investigate `openpyxl ` module, or `xlswriter`.
https://www.google.com/search?q=python+open+edit+and+save+excel+file&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALiCzsZ-locwlQXxdJ70UIlzq4trws8oZg%3A1657226002244&source=hp&ei=EkPHYryCDMqlgAap5IeADQ&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYsdRIhCV6_FShOfQp6t83fXvaxFqyhXd&ved=0ahUKEwi807H5z-f4AhXKEsAKHSnyAdAQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=python+open+edit+and+save+excel+file&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMggIIRAeEBYQHToHCCMQ6gIQJ1DAAljAAmC7BmgBcAB4AIABYIgBYJIBATGYAQCgAQKgAQGwAQo&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: If you want to use pandas `pd.DataFrame()`, you can do almost the same, you can load data to dataframe, check/amend, later save the dataframe back to excel, but, you will loose all the formating and placings and colors. You will need to setup them up from scratch like in the new excel file

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by calling it a dataframe instead

```
if next_monday == now:
    nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=MO(+2))
    hr_file_readable = hr_file_readable.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
    next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
    print(next_monday)

    if next_monday == pd.DataFrame(data=hr_file_readable).all:
        nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=TU(+2))
        next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
        print(next_monday)


if not next_monday == now:
    nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=MO(+2))
    next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
    print(next_monday)

    if next_monday == pd.DataFrame(data=hr_file_readable).all:
        nm = now - relativedelta(weekday=TU(+2))
        next_monday = nm.strftime("%#m/%#d/%#y")
        print(next_monday)
```

Comment: now save it back to excel and see if it is what you wanted :)